# how to integrate vaadin 7.1.15 with liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2?

Tags: vaadin, liferay-6, portlet, vaadin7

1. I removed the following from my liferay tomcat bundle

> liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN
>
> liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/vaadin.jar

2. Extracted

> VAADIN folder **from** vaadin-server.jar **into** liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN.

This extracts vaadinBootstrap.js which is needed by all Vaadin applications.

3. Extracted

> VAADIN folder from vaadin-themes.jar into
>       liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN.

```
This extracted all Vaadin themes.
```

4. Extracted

> VAADIN folder **from** vaadin-client-compiled.jar **into**
>   liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN.

This extracts the default widget set.

5. Copied the following jars into
   liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib

> vaadin-server.jar,
>
> vaadin-shared.jar,
>
> vaadin-shared-deps.jar,
>
> jsoup.jar

6. removed the version numbers from name of jars
7. created vaadin portlet project in my liferay sdk on eclipse.

This throws vaadin.jar missing exception.

My portlet cannot find the com.vaadin.Application.java class or the com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationPortlet2.java class, which are in the vaadin.jar file.

But this vaadin.jar file cannot be found in the downloaded all-in-one package.

Help me to resolve this.

thanks and regards

Comment: Its hard for me to understand question. Please consider correct grammar.

Comment: kukis   plz check now?

Comment: I need to go back to home :)